# restore mysql 5.0.77 backup to mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql

I am having backup of mysql version 5.0.77.

I want to restore backup of 5.0.77 to our new machin having mysql version 5.5

What is the procedure?

Comment: What have you already achieved?  What are the actual problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a logical backup generated with mysqldump, you should load it into mysql 5.5 without issues. You could check that logical backup was generated with the options `--triggers --events --comments --routines` to be more complete.